# How to redirect everything except root and some folders in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, cpanel

I am looking for .htaccess code that will redirect all traffic at mydomain.com to example.com/folder1 except the root of example.com and folder2, folder3 and folder4.
Summery:
Url to redirect - all files and folders at example.com
Redirect to -  to example.com/folder1
Exception - root, folder2,folder3,folder4

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1(/|$) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder2(/|$) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder3(/|$) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder4(/|$)

RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/folder1 [L,R=301]
```

EDIT:
Tried to use the above code to redirect but not sure if the code itself has issues because it doesn't seem to work as expected. What could be the problem?
The Problem: I want the redirection to exclude home page, folder2, folder3, folder4 otherwise redirect everything to to folder1

Comment: OK, fine, great you have a plan. Now you see, SO is _not_ a free coding service. If you need someone to do your work for you, then I suggest you hire a payer programmer. We are here to offer assistance with issues _in the code you implemented_. So you are required to solve the task _yourself_ and only if you get stuck with a specific question you cannot answer yourself, _then_ is the time to come here and ask _that specific question_.

Comment: @arkascha I actually have the code and it is here `RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1(/|$)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder2(/|$)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder3(/|$)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder4(/|$)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js(/|$)
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/folder1 [L,R=301]` .

Comment: Please add additional information to the question itself so that it is readable. Thanks. There is an `edit` link below your question. _Use it_ .

Comment: Now that you gave us the code the next obvious question from our side is: what is your actual question here? Your _specific_ question?

Comment: @arkascha hope the question is now clear. Thanks

Comment: We are getting closer, but this is still vague. What does "it doesn't seem to work as expected" actually mean? What does it do, as expected or not and what does it _not_ do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @arkascha The code currently redirects home page(example.com) to example.com/folder1. I expect the code to spare home and spare folder2,folder3 and folder4. Example when the user goes to example.com/explore, it should redirect to example.com/folder1/explore. Basically it should redirect everything except home and given subfolders. How do Imake it to spare home/root and those folders

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to your comments and the additional information you gave the question becomes more clear now.

I suggest this rule set, it should get you closer to what you try to achieve, though it still might need some tweaking...

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1/?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder2/?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder3/?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder4/?
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://example.com/folder1/$1 [END,R=301]
```

This rule set will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and in case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: The code works except when you go example.com/explore to redirects to example.com/folder1/404.shtml. Was wonderig where the `404.shtml` came from since its not part of the files in the directory. I expected it to go to example.com/folder1/explore. Other it is truthfully sparing the required folders

Comment: Corrected!! The `explore` folder was not yet in example.com/folder1. Had to include it. Thanks for the help